# incompatible types error for ArrayList.get(i);

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

List is an array list in which the user is prompted to enter words until they type "done".

```
    ArrayList<String> List =new ArrayList<String>();
```

I keep on getting the error of: "incompatible types" at the line:

```
    str = List.get(i);
```

Where str is a String

```
public int compareTo(ArrayList List, String words, int size)
{
    S1 drive = new S1 ();
    int result=0;
    int min=1;
    String str;
    while (result<min)
    { for(int i=0; i<size ;i++){
        str = List.get(i);
        result=words.compareTo(str);
        if (result<min)
            min=result;
        }  
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should name your variables using a lower case first letter. It's probably getting confused with `java.util.List`, the interface that defines the behavior of ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

You used a raw type in your `compareTo` method signature.  When type erasure occurs, the `get` method you're calling on `List` (confusingly named) is `Object`, not `String`, which `compareTo` expects in the `String` class.

Accept the non-raw `ArrayList` as a parameter.

```
public into compareTo(ArrayList<String> list, String words, int size)
```

(I've changed `List` to `list` to follow common Java naming conventions and to avoid a commonly used Java interface.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `compareTo` method gets a raw `ArrayList` argument, so you can't assign an element of that list to a String without casting.

In addition, I wouldn't use `List` as the variable name, since there's already a widely used interface with that name.

```
public int compareTo(ArrayList<String> list, String words, int size)
{
    S1 drive = new S1 ();
    int result=0;
    int min=1;
    String str;
    while (result<min) { 
        for(int i=0; i<size ;i++) {
            str = list.get(i);
            result=words.compareTo(str);
            if (result<min)
                min=result;
        }  
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function title:

```
public int compareTo(ArrayList<String> list, String words, int size)
```

and your line:

```
str = list.get(i);
```

The way you did before was related to `List` interface collection which isn't good to call a parameter like this

Comment: And also provide a type argument for the generic `ArrayList`. `ArrayList.get(...)` should return an `Object`, not a `String`. Only `ArrayList<String>.get(...)` will return a `String`.